# Computer wont display anything after new ram is installed

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, beep-code

After a couple years of having two ram sticks of different speeds (2400MHz and 2666MHz) I decided to buy a new ram stick of speed 2666MHz to replace the 2400. When I installed this ram, my computer will not display anything and outputs a beep code that I can't find information about seemingly anywhere.
The beep code is 1 short, long pause, 1 long, 3 short, short pause, 1 short.
My pc specs are:
Motherboard: Asus prime B360M-A,
GPU: GeForce GTX 1060.
To attempt to fix this, I have tried reseating RAM, using only my 2400MHz ram, only my old 2666MHz ram, using only my new 2666MHz ram, a different ram slot, reseating my GPU, unplugging my GPU and running from integrated graphics card, using a different port on my GPU; but none of these have worked as the same error is happening
I believe this is an issue with my motherboard as I have attempted the integrated graphics and different variations of the ram, but I wanted to check some other peoples opinions as I have no clue

Answer (score 0):

Listen closer to the beep output. The initial short beep is probably just the confirmation the computer has been turned on. Which leaves 1 long 3 short or 1 long and 4 short. Definitions to asus motherboard beep codes can be found [here](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1029959/). It says the following for both possibilities:

> 4. "One long and three short beeps" from speaker
>
> An anomaly is detected in the graphic card. If the graphic card needs
> an extra power supply, please ensure the power supply can provide
> enough wattage.
>
> 5. "One long and four short beeps" from speaker
>
> An anomaly is detected on CPU Fan Error or CPU  Over Temperature Error
> or CPU Over Voltage Error
>
> Please ensure your CPU and CPU Fan is installed correctly. If it still
> fails, please enter BIOS to load default BIOS or clear CMOS to try
> again